# PAN ID in ZigBee

Tags: communication, zigbee

Can a node in a network have multiple PAN IDs (if a node is overlapping a node between two personal area networks)?

For example: One PAN ID consists of {s1, s2, s3} and another consists of {s3, s4, s5}. I want to build an application were two different networks only communicate with each other through an intermediate node (here it is `s3`).

Is it possible?

Also, if I assign s3 PAN ID 0xFFFF (that is, broadcast) and the rest s1, s2 : 0XBBFF and s4 s5 as 0x AA33. Will all the messages of s1 s2 and s4 s5 arrive at s3?

Answer (score 5):

No, a node on the network can only be joined to a single PAN.  There's no such thing as overlapping PAN networks.

It is possible for a router to leave one network and join another, but it can only send and receive on one network at a time.

Answer (score 0):

SiLabs (Ember's) stack can support communication on more than one PAN ID (I believe right now the max is two).  I'm not sure if there is a nice out-of-the-box solution that will support this, but you could create an application using their dev kit that could talk on both PAN IDs.